# Javascript why FOR IN is a bad practice?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JavaScript “For …in” with Arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/javascript-for-in-with-arrays)

People always tell me that using FOR IN is a bad practice, please could you tell me why? And why is better to use for with i?

I always liked to use FOR IN because I use PHP too where I use `foreach` a lot and it's very similar to FOR IN in javascript :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Bad practice is not to understand the difference between **enumerating** over an *array object* and **iterating** over it. Otherwise `for...in` loop is excellent tool. There is big internal difference, but i will try to explain in the practical manner:

Syntax is: `for (string in object)`, where `object` is an instance of `Object` (and, naturally, any of its descendants) and `string` var receives property name of `object` on each loop iteration. But `Array` is an `Object` descendant too! So, it is perfectly legal to use:

```
var array = [0,1,2];
for (var property in array)
  alert(typeof property + '\t' + property + '\n' + typeof array[property] + '\t' + array[property]);
```

but simply **makes no sense** at all. Moreover, note the bracket notation above `[]`. This is a form of membership operator and must not be confused with array element access. First requires operand of type `string` and second - `number`. Lets break example above and create array with `var array = new Array(3)` instead. Loop works no longer, yet `array.length == 3` correctly.

Conclusion: use `for...in` for any objects except arrays. Use `for (var number = 0; number < array.length; number++)` with arrays.

By the way, JavaScript **objects** are similar with PHP's associative arrays (hashtables, if you insist on the proper term). Syntax is `var object = {string:value,anotherName:moreStuff}`. Here `for...in` comes handy!

[Further reading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)

Comment: See also David Humphrey's post [Iterating over Objects in JavaScript Quickly](http://vocamus.net/dave/?p=1205) - for array's it's much slower.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan the link is broken

Comment: *Iterating over Objects in JavaScript Quickly* is now at https://blog.humphd.org/vocamus-1205/. But when performance is in question, seek newer information; ten years is an extremely long time in JavaScript engine development..