# JavaScript For... in... returns hasObject?

Tags: javascript, browser

It's just that.  I've looked online and I've looked on StackOverflow and I don't see anyone talking about this.

Is it normal when an array is constructed such as:

```
_e = Array();
_e[0] = 'admin_adv_from_date_month';
_e[1] = 'admin_adv_from_date_day';
_e[2] = 'admin_adv_from_date_year';
_e[3] = 'admin_adv_to_date_month';
_e[4] = 'admin_adv_to_date_day';
_e[5] = 'admin_adv_to_date_year';
```

That when you run through it like so:

```
enableElements : function(elements)
{
        for ( var e in elements )
        {
            hForm.enableElement(elements[e]);
        }
}
```

The last thing e is set to is 'hasObject' in my code.  I had to implement a safe guard in 'enableElement', as e in this case returns null as 'hasObject' becomes a function:

```
enableElement : function(element)
    {
        var e = document.getElementById(element);
        if ( e )
        {
            e.disabled = false;
        }
    }
```

I'm running this on the latest Safari.  Yes I know I could be using all sorts of alternative browsers that can do all sorts of whizbang stuff, but Safari is what I am using for this project.

Is this normal browser behavior?  Why might this happen?

Comment: Ah yes, I must use the traditional for loop.  Thanks for correcting me guys and setting me on the right track.  Learned something today :-)

Comment: Just finished typing a short novel on that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261051/javascript-why-for-in-is-a-bad-practice/4273208#4273208 dont make me write another! :-) BTW, `_e = ['admin_adv_from_date_month','admin_adv_from_date_day','so on']`

Answer (score 4):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

> **`for...in`**
>
> "Iterates a specified variable over all **the properties** of an object, in arbitrary order. For each distinct property, the specified statement is executed."
>
> "Although it may be tempting to use this as a way to iterate over an Array, this is a bad idea."

You should not use `for...in` to iterate over arrays, it's meant to iterate over object properties. Use a good old `for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)` loop instead.

Answer (score 2):

You should not use `for in` to loop through an array.
Instead, use a normal `for` loop with an index.

To answer the question, `for in` will also enumerate all methods inherited from prototypes.

Answer (score 2):

Simple rule: don't use `for...in` to *iterate* an array, you're *enumerating* the array, and all the extra properties it may have.  You should use a normal `for` loop here, like this:

```
enableElements : function(elements)
{
    for (var i=0; i<elements.length; i++)
    {
        hForm.enableElement(elements[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use `.length`, not `for..in` for arrays.

```
enableElements : function(elements) {
    for (var i=0, l = elements.length; i<l; i++)
    {
        hForm.enableElement(elements[i]);
    }
```

Otherwise you risk enumerating through anything extended through `Object.prototype`. You can `.hasOwnProperty` check but why do so when `.length` is perfect?